# How do you output text of a selected radio button?

Tags: php, jquery

How do you output text of a selected radio button?

For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">My favourite color is red.
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">My favourite color is blue.
</form>

<span id="feedback"></span>
```

So, if I click the button with a value of red. How can I output the text "My favourite color is red." and have the text inside the span?

I only know how to echo the value, not the text.

Would appreciate an example!

Edited.

Comment: Give id to radio tag and use jQuery to get the text of selected radio button.

Comment: learn something called **JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: You have a syntax error too, fix that.

Comment: You want text in javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Once you submit a form, you will only get what the page is being sent through the form. There is no way of getting the exact text *next to* a radio button that isn't sent along with the form, but you can simply take the value and construct the text again.

If you are sending the form by POST, you could do the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
    echo 'My favorite color is '.htmlentities($_POST['color']);
}
```

Note the use of [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) – never trust user input. This function replaces characters like `<` to their corresponding HTML entity, e.g. `&lt;`. This way, a malicious user can't send some HTML tags as value and break your page.

If you want to send by GET, replace `$_POST['color']` with `$_GET['color']`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the text value with some help of JS to PHP. Should you look at the request details you will see only name and value are sent to PHP.